# I'm writing a spellchecking program, how do I replace ch in a string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

What am I doing wrong/what can I do?

```
import sys
import string

def remove(file):
    punctuation = string.punctuation
    for ch in file:
        if len(ch) > 1:
            print('error - ch is larger than 1 --| {0} |--'.format(ch))
        if ch in punctuation:
            ch = ' '
            return ch
        else:
            return ch

ref = (open("ref.txt","r"))
test_file = (open("test.txt", "r"))

dictionary = ref.read().split()
file = test_file.read().lower()
file = remove(file)
print(file)
```

This is in Python 3.1.2

Comment: I don't know python, but in most languages you can do `string[index]=a_character`.  Once again, I don't know python, so that might not compile.

Comment: You cannot do that in python. Strings are immutable.

Comment: related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/265960/best-way-to-strip-punctuation-from-a-string-in-python

Answer (score 2):

In this code...:

```
for ch in file:
        if len(ch) > 1:
```

the weirdly-named `file` (besides breaking the best practice of not hiding builtin names with your own identifier) is not a file, it's a string -- which means unicode, in Python 3, but that makes no difference to the fact that the loop is returning single characters (unicode characters, not bytes, in Python 3) so `len(ch) == 1` is absolutely guaranteed by the rules of the Python language.  Not sure what you're trying to accomplish with that test (rule out some subset of unicode characters?), but, whatever it *is* you thing you're achieving, I assure you that you're not achieving it and should recode that part.

Apart from this, you're returning -- and therefore exiting the function -- immediately, and thereby exiting the function and returning just one character (the first one in the file, or a space if that first one was a punctuation character).

The suggestion to use the `translate` method, which I saw in another answer, is the right one, but that answer used the wrong version of `translate` (one applying to byte strings, *not* to unicode strings as you need for Python 3).  The proper unicode version is simpler, and transforms the whole body of your function into just two statements:

```
trans = dict.fromkeys(map(ord, string.punctuation), ' ')
return file.translate(trans)
```

Answer (score 1):

In python, strings are immutable, so you need to create a new string with your changes.

There are a few ways to do this:

One is using a list comprehension to inspect the characters and only returning the non-punctuation.

```
def remove(file):
  return ''.join(ch for ch in file if ch not in string.punctuation)
```

You could also call functions to test the character or translate the character which you might have throw "weird character" exceptions or do some other functionality:

```
def remove(file):
  return ''.join(TranslateCh(ch) for ch in file if CheckCh(ch))
```

Another alternative is the `string` module, providing `replace` or `translate`.  Translate provides a nice (and more efficient than building a list) mechanism for this, see Alex's answer.

Or... you could collect a list over a `for`loop and join it at the end, but that's a little "unpythonic".

Comment: `string.maketrans` is for byte strings, and deprecated in Python 3 in favor of `bytes.maketrans` -- definitely not what the OP needs in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the re (regular expression) module.  It has a "sub" function to replace strings that match regular expressions.